# Different results of adding UIBezierPath in UIKit and SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uikit, uibezierpath

I'm trying to add an arc to my SpriteKit scene with **SKShapeNode**. If I draw an arc with **UIView** like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)) radius:64.0f startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*4/3 clockwise:YES];
    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
    path.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    [path stroke];
}
```

I get the following:

[image]

And I get what I expect.  If I draw a similar arc through **SKScene** like:

```
- (void)createCircle {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointZero radius:128.0f startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*4/3 clockwise:YES];
    SKShapeNode *ring = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:path.CGPath];
    ring.name = @"ring";
    ring.lineWidth = 20;
    ring.strokeColor = [SKColor magentaColor];
    ring.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds),CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
    [self.scene addChild:ring];
}
```

I get the following picture. That's not what I expect to see. It goes counter-clockwise. Why don't I get an arc like the first picture? Do I need to flip the axes or something? My development target is iOS 8.4 if that matters.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2D coordinate system in UIKit and SpriteKit is different.

- [UIKit view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW5) has the origin at the upper-left corner.
- [SpriteKit view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH3-SW14) has the origin at the lower-left corner.

To achieve the same arc, modify the `path`

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointZero radius:128.0f startAngle:0 endAngle:-M_PI*4/3 clockwise:NO];
```

Comment: I have heard of that, I guess.  Thanks.